# Svelte giving me 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined'

Tags: javascript, svelte, nlg

I'm trying to use a natural language generation library called RosaeNLG with my Svelte app but whenever I import any variable from the JavaScript file that 'requires' rosaenlg I get an error saying 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined'.

Rosae is a library for node.js or client side (browser) execution, based on the Pug template engine.

I have read similar issues with Svelte that have been solved by changing the 'requires' syntax to different forms of 'import'. For instance: 'import rosaenlgPug from "rosaenlg"'; 'import * as rosaenlgPug from "rosaenlg"'; var rosaenlgPug = import("rosaenlg")'; 'import("rosaenlg")'.

All of these variations fail to rollup and eventually give the error: 'FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory'.

Edit: I have managed to get an old version of Rosae working within a svelte file using the following code:

```
<script>
let rendered = "Busy...";

const onRosaeNlgLoad = () => {

    let array = ['x','y','z'];
    
    let template = `
mixin variable
  | this is a Rosae template #[+syn('synonym1', 'synonym2')]`
    
    rendered = rosaenlg_en_US.render(template, {
        language: 'en_US',
        fruits: fruits
    })
}
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/rosaenlg@1.20.2/dist/rollup/rosaenlg_tiny_en_US_1.20.2_comp.js" on:load="{onRosaeNlgLoad}"></script>
</svelte:head>

<h1>{rendered}!</h1>
```

However, I still haven't been able to get it working in a JS file or by linking the template from a pug file, as instructed in the [Rosae examples](https://rosaenlg.org/rosaenlg/1.20.2/tutorials/tutorial_en_US.html).

I'm trying the following in a JS file:

```
import * as rosaenlgPug from "rosaenlg";

let array = ['x', 'y', 'z']

let result = rosaenlgPug.renderFile('tuto.pug', {
    language: 'en_US',
    element: array[0]
});
 
export { result };
```

But when import the 'result' variable into a svelte file I get: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require$$0$6 is not defined'.

Any suggestions about how to render a library like this in Svelte would be hugely appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: post the code pls

Comment: I've just updated. Thanks

Comment: Which template did you choose to initialise your svelte app and with which version?

Comment: Hi @bigquestionsasked - this question is still open. If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below any answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you want to know. Otherwise, please choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside an answer) to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer (to close the question). That would help us out. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with `rosaenlg`, but below is a minimal `SvelteKit` project that could run after specifying CommonJS libraries in `svelte.config.js` as instructed by the [FAQ](https://kit.svelte.dev/faq#packages)

#### Folder Structure

```
├── sveltekit-project/        // Root
|   ├── src/
|   |   ├── routes/
|   |   |   ├── index.svelte
|   |   |   └── tuto.js
|   |   ├── app.html
|   |   ...
|   ├── svelte.config.js
|   ...
```

#### /src/routes/tuto.js

```
import rosaenlgPug from 'rosaenlg';

const phones = [{
  name: 'OnePlus 5T',
  colors: ['Black', 'Red', 'White'],
}, {
  name: 'OnePlus 5',
  colors: ['Gold', 'Gray'],
}, {
  name: 'OnePlus 3T',
  colors: ['Black', 'Gold', 'Gray'],
}];

const template = `
mixin colors
  | the phone's available colors are
  eachz color in phone.colors with { separator:',', last_separator:'and', end:'.' }
    | #{color}

- let phone;
each phoneElt in phones
  - phone = phoneElt;
  p #{phone.name} . #[+colors]
`;

// As an endpoint
export async function get() {
  const res = rosaenlgPug.render(template, {
    language: 'en_US',
    phones: phones
  });
  return { body: { res }};
};
```

##### /src/routes/index.svelte

```
<script context='module'>
  // Fetch in load for client side usage
  export const load = async ({ fetch }) => {
    const data = await fetch('/tuto').then(r => r.json())
    const { res } = data
    return { props: { res }}
  }
</script>

<script>
  export let res
</script>


<p>{@html res}</p>
```

##### /svelte.config.js

```
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        // hydrate the <div id="svelte"> element in src/app.html
        target: '#svelte',
        vite: {
            optimizeDeps: {
                include: ['rosaenlg']
            }
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, just some things to try.

There are a few possibilities - the message is not terribly helpful.  I've run into this with other packages and here's what I did to resolve it:

First, is there a required package that has not been installed? What does the full error message say, after the `ReferenceError: require is not defined`? I've seen this happen with `http2-proxy` or with `@snowpack/plugin-webpack` or etc. E.g.

```
npm install --save-dev @snowpack/plugin-webpack
```

Also, if using snowpack, you might have a `snowpack.config.mjs`
file.  Try renaming it to just `snowpack.config.js`

*(In my case, this instantly fixed it, this 2nd step)*

Another thing to try: In your config file, try swapping `require` for `import` or vice versa.  For e.g.

```
const pkg = require('http2-proxy');
```

to

```
const pkg = import('http2-proxy');
```